# How to hide menu items?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

With a `<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>` how do I hide an ApplicationBarMenuItem programmatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can set their `Visibility` programmatically, but you can use `IsEnabled` on them?

If you really need to hide/show them, then try adding/removing them in code instead of in XAML - see some sample code for adding in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431786(VS.92).aspx and for modifying in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh394044(v=VS.92).aspx

Comment: :) Xaml does have its benefits - especially for databinding - and it is good if you can master Blend (personally, I'll keep trying!)

Comment: @Start - True, but `ApplicationBar` does not subclass DependencyObject and thus is not bindable.

Comment: @Richard - thanks, agreed. If you do need binding, try - http://blog.humann.info/post/2010/08/27/How-to-have-binding-on-the-ApplicationBar.aspx (there is an update somewhere for Mango)